# Create a regex that includes decimal numbers and a maximum of length

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern that accepts decimal numbers and the maximum length should be 3.
These are the regex I tried but didn't work

```
new RegExp('d{1-3}')
new RegExp('^[0-9]{3}$')
```

I want to achive to allow the decimal numbers between 0-999.

For example 185.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *didn't work* is not very specific. What was the string you used it on and what was the result? You are also not matching the dot or colon. A bit unclear what you expect.

Comment: You should also define length.  E.g. for 3.14, the length in characters is 4; there are 3 numbers, and 2 after the decimal point.  I assume you mean character length.

Comment: Also, do you want to allow for negative numbers, and if so, do you count the - sign in your length?

Comment: Just so youre aware `d{1-3}` matches the _literal character_ "d" exactly 3 times, and `^[0-9]{3}$` matches a number exactly 3 times

Comment: @super I just want first to return true or false. I used for example 185.4

Comment: @JosephDoggie I just updated the question. If you can check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this: `^[1-9]{0,3}$`

it only accept numbers with max length of 3

example: 123

and if you want it with complex numbers use this:

```
^[1-9]{0,3}([,.][0-9]{0,3})?$
```

example: 154.234

Comment: Doesn't work with decimal numbers, since I need it to be for example 185.4

Comment: if you want to reduce digits after dot to one just replace last 3 to 1

Comment: I think by complex do you mean 'real' or decimal instead of complex?  A complex number could be in the form "1 + 2i" or if you are an EE "1 + j2", sometimes there would be a multiplier with the squareroot(-1), i.e. i or j, that establishes the 'y-coordinate' in the complex plane.

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to do it, which matches any number b/w 0 and 999 including decimal values (unlimited)

```
^(\d{,3}(\.)?(?(2)\d*|$))$

#  should start and ends with a digit
# \d{,3} : match at most 3 digit
# (\.)? : optional period
# ?(?(2) : if period exist match the following pattern
# \d* : match any number of digits after period
# $ : else it should be end of pattern
```

https://regex101.com/r/B8jRG6/1

Answer (score 1):

```
regExp ^\d+((\.)|(\.\d{1,3})?)$
```

Comment: Why should the OP, I, or anyone else "try this"? Instead of putting a non-sentence in your answer, please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Can I limit it to be only 999 maximum value

Comment: Yes,you can,add maximim char in your regexp like this ^\d{1,3}+((\.)|(\.\d{1,3})?)$

Comment: Your answer is working just is that I'm getting this kind of error.

Invalid regular expression: /^d{1,3}+((.)|(.d{1,3})?)$/: Nothing to repeat.